# Spark TaskMetrics bytesRead

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[SparkListenerTaskEnd](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerTaskEnd) provides a val to get the TaskMetrics. In turn, [TaskMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/TaskMetrics.html) provides access to various metrics as well. When I try to use InputMetrics of TaskMetrics to get the bytes read I see 0 all the time, even though I'm reading data from `hdfs`. I do use my custom-made source (not `parquet` or `avro`) to pump data into `Dataframe`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Would it not be possible to monitor the amount of data that has been read for that particular task?

VK